# posting data to AND from multiple servers securely with ONE SSL certificate?

Tags: php, security, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

Here's the situation:

I'm working on an open source web application (in PHP) that will be distributed to domain owners (abbit like WordPress).

Now I (my server) needs to communicate with my users (users server). I'm going to be using cURL to transfer data between servers (using POST).

The only problem is, I have a SSL certificate, but the users won't have one. So the users server will be able to talk to my server without some evil b******* eavesdropping, but my server will not be able to talk to my users server, securely.

And I certainly do not want to require users to purchase SSL certificates in order to use the application.

I was wondering if there is a way to get away with only using one SSL certificate and still manage to POST data to and from securely?

I'm also open to any alternative suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post a request to call your server back (and pass some unique ID of the data to be requested from your server), so that servers connect to your server as clients, pass the ID and get their information.

The question, though, is what you need the certificate for. If you want to authenticate those servers (or ensure that your data only reaches legitimate servers), then you need those servers to have valid certificates (BTW They are not called SSL certificates, the naming is wrong). Otherwise spoofing the server is easy.